# When is a series of sums the sum of the series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In general, if $\Sigma_n (a_n+b_n)$ converges, then it may not be that $\Sigma_n a_n$ and $\Sigma_n b_n$ converge; for example, consider $\Sigma_n (1/n-1/n)$.

If instead we know $\Sigma_n a_n$ and $\Sigma_n b_n$ converge, what can we say about $\Sigma_n (a_n+b_n)$?  I know that if the convergence of the first two sums is absolute, then the third converges.  Can we make any conclusions when the convergence is not absolute? I tried to think of a counterexample but couldn't find one.

Comment: If $s_n \to s, t_n \to t$ then $s_n+t_n \to s+t$.

Comment: Haha, now I feel stupid for not seeing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard result.  Let $A_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and $B_n=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i$ be the partial sums.  Saying that $\sum_ia_i$ converges is exactly saying that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ exists.  If $\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n$ exists as well, then the limit law $\lim_{n\to\infty}(A_n+B_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n$ gives $\sum_i(a_i+b_i)=\sum_ia_i+\sum_ib_i$. So the sum converges.